# Get cell value when click button in listview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I create a listview, and put button in every row of a table cell. in button click event , how to get the value in table , like Aitline, ArrCity or the index of items.

// in aspx

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <ul>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />    
        </ul>                
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-hover">
                <th><%#Eval("Airline")%></th>
                <th><%#Eval("DepCity")%></th> 
                <th><%#Eval("DepTime")%></th> 
                <th><%#Eval("FlyTime")%> 分鐘</th> 
                <th><%#Eval("ArrTime")%></th> 
                <th><%#Eval("ArrCity")%></th> 
                <th class="success"><%#Eval("TotalFare")%></th>
                <th><asp:Button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="PayButton" runat="server" Text="Pay" OnClick="PayButton_OnClick"/></th>
            </table>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <p>Nothing here.</p>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

//in C# click event in PayButton

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Ticket> TicketList = new List<Ticket>();

    this.ListView1.DataSource = TicketList;
    this.ListView1.DataBind();
}

protected void PayButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // how to get table cell value here?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the DataKeyNames attribute. For example:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID, Name" >
```

and get the value this way in code-behind:

```
protected void PayButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem item = (sender as LinkButton).NamingContainer as ListViewItem;
    int id = (int)ListView1.DataKeys[item.DataItemIndex].Values["ID"];
    string name = (string)ListView1.DataKeys[item.DataItemIndex].Values["Name"];
}
```

Comment: @KenChu: Yeah! You're so great, my friend :))